# ssh login fails with "The system is going down for reboot in 3 minutes!"

Tags: ssh, login, shutdown, cron

I have a Beaglebone Black (armv7l) running Ubuntu 14.04.3. I leave the system running, and about once a week I suddenly get this error when trying to log in over ssh:

```
The system is going down for reboot in 3 minutes!

Authentication failed.
```

I have tried waiting 3 minutes to 3 hours and the message never changes. As far as I can tell, I'm completely locked out from this point.

I'm guessing this is caused by a cron job I have that runs every day:

```
0 4 * * * bash -c '/sbin/shutdown -r +$[RANDOM\%40]'
```

My current guess is that cron kicks off the shutdown with this, but something goes wrong and it gets hung up, not allowing logins. I have a root password, but no access to the root user, so I can't log in at all.

The only thing that seems fishy is that the command produces a syntax error when run by itself:

```
bash: RANDOM\%40: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\%40")
```

But it seems to work otherwise, the system goes down and comes back up reliably 6/7 days.

I have no idea where I got this command from, but if I was doing it today I would use

```
0 4 * * * bash -c '/sbin/shutdown -r +$[$RANDOM%40]'
```

But I'm not really sure if that would solve my problem.

Does anyone know why the shutdown would prevent login like this? Is it something with the cron job, or could it be something else entirely that I haven't thought of?

Comment: `%` is a special character in crontabs and needs to be escaped there; bash will see plain `%`

Comment: Okay, so that explains why it works in cron but not when run manually. Thanks!

Comment: `cron` isn't `bash`, and parses command lines differently. That's one reason all my `cron` entries invoke scripts.